# problems with remove jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a label "a" dynamically with jQuery to others of a button to remove it but the jQuery selector did not take the class button. [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/ccdiego5/rnm3waky/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {                        
               // Agregar campo
    $("#addautor").click(function () {                                                                                                    
        var autor = $("#autor").val();                           
            if (autor.length > 0) {                        
                var data = "<label class='etiqueta' id='hola'>" + autor + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class='btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-hover borrar' title='Eliminar'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>";
                       $("#autorlist").append(data);
                   }                                        
    });            
               $(".etiqueta").click(function(){
                   alert("fino");
               });          
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="" class="col-sm-2 control-label dubline">
    Autor(es) <br> <small>Encargado(s)</small>
</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">
            
        <input type="text"  class="form-control" autocomplete="off" id="autor" name="autor">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="addautor">
    ... <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span> Agregar
    </button>                  
</span>
</input>

        </div><!-- /input-group -->                                     
        <p class="help-block" id="autorlist"></p>
      </div><!-- /col-sm-10 -->
</div><!-- /form-group -->
```

Comment: What exactly are the problems you're having?

Comment: What is the problem you are having?  I looked at your fiddle but nowhere in it do you describe the problem you are trying to fix.  you can remove a class from an element like this: `$('#whatever').removeClass('myclassname');`.

Comment: im trying to access a class 'borrar' but jquery doesnt take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation:

```
           $(".etiqueta").click(function(){
               alert("fino");
           });
```

Should be:

```
           $("#autorlist").on("click", ".etiqueta", function(){
               $(this).closest('label').remove();
           });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/rnm3waky/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that your alert doesn't fire when clicking the delete icon, it's because you need to use event delegation on dynamically added elements. Change your click function to:

```
$('.help-block').on('click', ".etiqueta", function () {
    $(this).closest('label').remove();
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ytab6ut9/1/)**

Comment: Yeap... this is it... I made an update/1 of the OP fiddle.. but same answer as here, so... +1

Comment: i changed the code to this 

i've changed my code to this all i want to do is, when clicking the delete button remove de entire label. i think something to dom with the parent function instead of an alert

$('.autorlist').on('click', ".borrar", function () {
    alert("fino");
});

Comment: How did we go from "it works" and accepting my answer to unaccepting it? Something change?